# How to search in umbraco 8.1 using custom property in where clause

Tags: linq, umbraco

var a = Nodes.Children.Where("CustomProperty == @0", "Value").First();

Throwing error
{"No property or field 'CustomProperty' exists in type 'IPublishedContent'"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use strongly typed models - e.g.:

```
var a = Nodes.Children<PageType>.Where(p => p.CustomProperty == "Value").First();
```

There are no dynamics in Umbraco 8 anymore, and the APIs have been simplified.  Take a look at Shannon Deminick's "cheat sheet" from the uDuf conference earlier this year:

https://shazwazza.com/media/1032/uduf-2019.pdf

Comment: Robert I can use strongly typed models in umbraco view but in my api controller it shows below errors
1. The type or namespace name 'ModelName' could not be found
2. The property 'IPublishedContent.Children' cannot be used with type arguments

Although I have switched ModelsMode value to DLL and generated models, restart VS but unable to get models in my api controller
I am sharing my full code, Please have a look

**var Node = Umbraco.Content(parentId);
var a = Node.Children<ModelName>().Where(x => x.CustomProperty  = "Value").First();**

Comment: Thank you for response Robert It was missing Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels dll Now I added manually

Comment: glad you got it sorted :)